# how to convert string object to json object in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have changed data in string format where it was like [object object] but I want to change the string object into json object I tried json.parse but it not changing into json object

can you please suggest me where I am doing wrong and how to fix this

```
try {
  var timekeep = await Orders.findAndCountAll({
    where: {
      cid: orders_info.cid,
    },
    order: [
      ['id', 'DESC']
    ],
    limit: 1,
    raw: true,
  });
  var cont1 = JSON.stringify(timekeep.rows[0]);
  var obj = JSON.parse(cont1);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err)
}

console.log('org data' + timekeep)
console.log('data as string' + cont1);

// now when I am trying to print
console.log('data as json' + obj);
```

the output of the console.logs

```
org data [object Object]

data as sttring{"id":4006,"mid":1,"cid":41,"wid":7138,"oid":null,"status":null,"options":null,"starttime":"2018-08-15T06:08:55.000Z","duration":null,"ordertotal":50,"counter":null,"closetime":null}

data as json [object object]
```

Comment: `var obj = JSON.parse(obj);` => `var obj = JSON.parse(cont1);`

Comment: FYI, objects are objects.  They can be represented as JSON, which is a string.  So saying "string object" and "JSON object" makes no sense.  Object or JSON - that's it.

Comment: Also, change the last line to `console.log(obj);` - It's already an object.  When you do `console.log("something" + object)` it automatically turns the object into a string and appends it to the string you're logging.  If you want to log with a bit of text to tell you what you've logged then use a comma like this... `console.log("data as object", obj);`

Comment: Just `console.log(obj)` it's already a json object.

Comment: @MoadEnnagi There's no such thing as a json object.

Comment: @Archer, [Json specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159)

Comment: @MoadEnnagi  Yes, **JavaScript Object Notation**, is a way of representing objects as strings.  They are NOT objects.  You should read the link you posted as that explains it very clearly.

Comment: @Archer, you are right,  "JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) is a lightweight, text-based, language-independent data interchange format"

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see you are already converting it to a JSON with `var obj = JSON.parse(cont1);`

So you already have a JSON, it's just that how you're printing it is wrong. To it with a comma instead of +.

```
console.log('data as json', obj)
```

The + is doing a string concatenation, and it's attempting to concatenate a string with an object

Answer (score 0):

After String concat it prints `data as json [object object]`. if you put `,` instead of `+` will print that object correctly. In the snippet, you can see the difference.

```js
var jsonstr = '{"id":4006,"mid":1,"cid":41,"wid":7138,"oid":null,"status":null,"options":null,"starttime":"2018-08-15T06:08:55.000Z","duration":null,"ordertotal":50,"counter":null,"closetime":null}';

console.log(JSON.parse(jsonstr));

console.log('data as json' , JSON.parse(jsonstr));

console.log('data as json' + JSON.parse(jsonstr));
```

Answer (score 0):

console.log just the object; 
if you want log object and a string use , instead of +

```js
jsonString = '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}'

jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString)

console.log(jsonObject) // logging just the object

console.log('jsonObjectName' , jsonObject) // logging object with string 

console.log('jsonObject.key1 : ' +  jsonObject.key1 ) 


// this may come handy with certain IE versions
function parseJSON(resp){
    if (typeof resp === 'string') 
        resp = JSON.parse(resp);
    else
        resp = eval(resp);
    return resp;
}
```